# msdownload.tmp, annoying folder

Tags: windows-7

A lot of msdownload.tmp and other.tmp folders gets created automatically in my d:\ location (windows 7). I have runned a virus check with bit defender but it was clean.

I have changed the Security permissions of d:\ to only read, write, execute and nothing else. Has it anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msdownload.tmp is created by MS Internet Explorer.  It wll be created irrespective of the security settings as it comes from the OS itself.

This may be annoying but it isn't a problem.  You can just delete it but it will recreate.